# How to refresh page each time you press submit button?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

I'm new to Javascript and HTML.

I have the following form in **HTML**:

```
<div id="form-select">
    <form id="date_form" onsubmit="return myFunction();">
        <datalist id="dates">
            <option value="February 7">February 7</option>
            <option value="February 14">February 14</option>
            <option value="February 21">February 21</option>
            <option value="February 28">February 28</option>
        </datalist>
        <input type="text" class="input" name="data" id="date" value="" list="dates" placeholder="pick a date"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
 </div>
```

Here's the **javascript** in a file called script.js. The js file is linked in the header as `<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" />`:

```
function myFunction(){
   var input = document.getElementById("date").value;
   if(input==="February 7"){
      document.getElementById('w1').innerHTML =  document.getElementById('w1').innerHTML + "<h2> HEADING </h2>";
   }
   return false;
 };
```

When I fill out the form and hit submit, the javascript correctly executes the function and adds "HEADING." However, when I press submit again, it adds "HEADING" a second time under the first instance of it.

How do I make it so that the page "refreshes" each time submit is pressed?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how this could add a second heading. It replaces the HTML of `w1` every time, it doesn't add to it.

Comment: yeah barmar is right.. it will always replace the innerHTML of w1

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I fixed the code to what it should read: document.getElementById('w1').innerHTML =  document.getElementById('w1').innerHTML + inner.h"<h2> HEADING </h2>";   I do this because the code iterates through an array at some point to find out how many HEADINGs to add; so if there are 2 elements in the array, it'll add HEADING twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use

```
window.location.reload();
```

In your Submit event code..

Comment: this code will help out to refresh the page.But, I guess Goelv doesn't require to refresh this page to achieve functionality.

Comment: he clearly mentioned "How do I make it so that the page "refreshes" each time submit is pressed?".....  And the sentence (so that the page "refreshes") clearly says that page refresh is re needed ..

Comment: Just one question, how does he is going to hold the value if page is refreshed ?

Comment: Why he need to hold the value... Form will use to send the information and after sending the info he wants to refresh the page and the above code will do the same if placed in right place

Comment: **When I fill out the form and hit submit, the javascript correctly executes the function and adds "HEADING."** so this means that he wants to show the value on the heading.. anyways I guess @goelv is right person to comment about the requirement

Comment: Thanks for the comments. What I'm looking for is the following: The user enters a specific date which populates "HEADING." When the user clicks submit again (with any date), the current code adds a second "HEADING" under the first "HEADING" (i.e. the page will show the following: HEADINGHEADING. I want it so that when the user clicks "submit" a second time, the page refreshes and the code executes so that the user only sees "HEADING" once.

Comment: @goelv why you dont try to empty the innerHTML of w1  then append with Heading

Comment: I tried the code above. The issue is that HEADING appears for about 1 second before disappearing

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery, `bind('submit', function(e){ e.preventDefault; ....; })`

```
$('#date_form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var input = document.getElementById("date").value;
    if(input==="February 7"){
        document.getElementById('w1').innerHTML = "<h2> HEADING </h2>";
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I tried this method, but it then fails to populate "HEADING"

Answer (score -1):

Found another way around the issue. I added the statement:

```
 document.getElementById('week').innerHTML = "";
```

at the beginning of each call of the function. That way, every time the user clicks submit, the div is emptied out before it is repopulated.